# How far can gems fall before they kill you?

Tags: quarries-of-scred

I hadn't noticed this in the game yet, but I just read this line in the game's readme:

> Stones will kill you if they are one or more squares above you, gems can also kill you if they fall too far.

I've had gems land on me from a few spaces high with no consequences (they just got collected).  How far below a gem do I need to be before I should worry about having it land on me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Copied from the developer's [comment on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/QuarriesOfScred/comments/2gf85z/question_how_far_do_gems_need_to_fall_before_they/ckmma2j).**

= = = = = = = =

Let's have a look at the code:

```
else if(tQuarry[w][h].getWeight() * tQuarry[w][h].getDistanceFallen() > PlayerHardness || tQuarry[w][h].getID().equals("Stone") == true)
```

This line basically determines if something is going to squish the crap out of the player.

PlayerHardness is set to 10 earlier in the program, and objects have different weights.

- Stones have Weight 10 (though they instakill anyway)
- Unsunnium has weight 2
- Ninthronium has weight 10
- Powercells have weight 10
- Dropbears have weight 10,000

So, from this, we can see that Ninthronium & Batteries will kill you if they drop 2 squares or more. Unsunnium takes about 6 squares to kill you, while Dropbears will remove you from existence at any distance.

Thanks for asking this one - I haven't looked at that particular bit of code in about... 6 months? So it was good to hunt it down for laughs.